# To locate div which inserted and generated by script over the other elemnts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to do that after a button is clicked a new div will be generated and inserted over the other elements on the page. I'm write the following markup:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="d1">
    </div>
    <div id="d2">
    </div>
    <div id="d3">
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="but"/>
</div>
```

styles:

```
#d1{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: black;
}
#d2{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
#d3{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

and script:

```
var but=document.getElementById("but");
var d3=document.getElementById("d3");
var p=document.createElement("div");
p.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute; top:400, background-color: grey;width:10px; height:10px;");
var parent= document.getElementById("parent");
but.onclick=function(){
    parent.insertBefore(p,d3);
}
```

But after I'm click a button the div insert under the other div. This is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9MtQN/1/) example. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you used a comma instead of a semicolon after top:400 :

```
position:absolute; top:400, background-color: grey;
```

The corect code is:

```
position:absolute; top:400; background-color: grey;
```

Demo: http://fiddle.jshell.net/9MtQN/2/

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using JQuery's append(); to add extra layers of colors over the ones you have already set.

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $('#over').append('<div id="dt"></div>');
});
```

See this Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jLCuD/